# jQuery Validation doesn't highlight my select field on error

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-validate

I am trying to apply a drop down validation (so if the value is equal to 0 of a `<select><option value="0">`) then it applies a background-color of yellow as it does for the rest of my input fields. Here is my code:

```
<script src="jq.js"></script>
<script src="validate.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
  "selectNone",
  function(value, element) {
    if (element.value == "0")
    {
   element.css({"border" : "1px solid #f00", "background-color" : "#ffffcb"});
      return false;
    }
    else return true;
  },
  "Please select an option."
);

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".form_validate").validate({
  onfocusout: true,
  rules: {
   zip: {
     required: true,
     number: true
   },
   phone: {
    required: true,
    number: true
   },
   select_debt: {
    required: true,
    selectNone: true
   },
   select_state: {
    required: true,
    selectNone: true
   }
    }

 });
 $("input.required, .select").blur(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val == "" || val == "0") {
   $(this).css({"border" : "1px solid #f00", "background-color" : "#ffffcb"});
  } else {
   $(this).css({"border" : "1px solid #ccc", "background-color" : "#fff"});
  }
 });
 function isValidPhoneDigits(val) {
  var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
  var floatRegex = /^((\d+(\.\d *)?)|((\d*\.)?\d+))$/;

  if(intRegex.test(val) || floatRegex.test(val)) {
     return true;
  } else {return false}

  if(intRegex.test(val) || floatRegex.test(val)) {
   return true;
  } else {return false}
 }
 $(".zip").blur(function(){
  if ( isValidPhoneDigits($(this).val()) && $(this).val().length == 5 ) {
   $(this).css({"border" : "1px solid #ccc", "background-color" : "#fff"});
   } else {
   $(this).css({"border" : "1px solid #f00", "background-color" : "#ffffcb"});
   }
 });
 $("a.popup").click(function(){
  var href_link = $(this).attr("href");
  window.open(href_link,"popup", "menubar=no,width=430,height=360,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,scrollbars=yes");
  return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

I have included jquery and validation at top. I have also declared a new validation method called selectNone which should check if the value is 0 and set the bg color to yellow.

Here is my html if that helps:

```
<form class="form_validate">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table">
 <tr>
     <td class="al_r">
         First Name
        </td>
        <td>
         <input value="" type="text" name="firstname" class="required" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="al_r">Last Name</td>
        <td><input value="" type="text" name="lastname" class="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="al_r">Address</td>
        <td><input value="" type="text" name="address" class="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="al_r">Zip</td>
        <td><input value="" type="text" id="zip" name="zip" class="required zip" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="al_r">City</td>
        <td><input value="" type="text" name="city" class="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="al_r">State</td>
        <td><select class="required select" name="select_state"><option value="">Select State</option><option value="1">California</option><option value="2">Alabama</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="al_r">Email</td>
        <td><input value="" type="text" name="email" class="required email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="al_r">Phone</td>
        <td><input value="" type="text" name="phone" class="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="al_r">Approximate Credit Card Debt</td>
        <td><select class="required select"  name="select_debt">
          <option value="">Please choose debt amount</option>
          <option value="1">$0-$9,999</option>
                <option value="2">$10,000-$19,999</option>
                <option value="2">$20,000-$29,999</option>
                <option value="2">$30,000-$39,999</option>
                <option value="2">$40,000-$49,999</option>
                <option value="2">$50,000+</option>
            </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
         <input type="image" src="images/check_elig.gif" height="38" width="300" style="border:none; height:38px; margin-left:20px;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" class="al_r small">
         May not be available in your state.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for any help as to why its not working.

Comment: If you have solved it yourself, why don't you post a brief solution here (and accept it to earn a badge)

Answer (score 5):

We tell jQuery to highlight the errored fields by generally putting the style for the `input` element, for example:

```
input.error {
    border: 2px solid #CC0000
}
```

Ensure that you add the style for the select elements as well, like:

```
select.error {
    border: 2px solid #CC0000
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
<option value="">Please choose debt amount</option>
```

But you're testing for `value == "0"` so you either need to change the `<option>` value or the logic of the `selectNone` method.

Comment: That isn't the issue, i changed it and were still on the same boat :(

Comment: Use Firebug or add an alert to the beginning of the selectNone method to see if the validation plugin is calling it. Also, it looks like you're using .value and .css on the same object. If it is a jQuery object, then only .css will work and .value should produce a JavaScript error. If it is a DOM object, then .css will not work and will produce a JavaScript error.

Comment: @Angel, please explain the issue then.  This is absolutely how you must setup a `select` item if you want to use with the jQuery Validate plugin.  It won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that `<select>` tags sometimes are left out by validators because they don't fall under the normal `<input>` tags.  Make sure the vaildator is looking for `<select>` tags to validate.

Answer (score 0):

select.error doesn't work since select is actually hidden by jQuery Mobile. Instead, there is a wrapping DIV that implements a nice select. Thanks to this we can style it nicely but on the other hand this generates this error styling problem.

Try this solution [jQuery Validate - Add Error Class to Parent Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941662/jquery-validate-add-error-class-to-parent-div). It seems work fine. You will have to write JS code since you probably will want to use jQuery validation and error class will NOT be assigned to select wrappers...

Dmitry Kresin, [Web development](http://ardas.dp.ua)