# jQuery Validate - Add Error Class to Parent Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validate plugin, and can never find a good way to display errors for checkboxes.  I'd like to highlight all of the checkbox labels in red if none are selected, and decide to do this by adding an error class to the div that contains the checkboxes and checkbox labels.  However, it doesn't seem to be adding the class.  Am I not selecting the div correctly?

HTML:

```
<div class="left-aligned indent">

    <label id="id_label" for="id" class="label">Items:</label>

    <div class="select-group">

        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="1" id="item_1" />
        <label class="checkbox">Item #1</label><br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="1" id="item_2" />
        <label class="checkbox">Item #2</label><br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="items" value="1" id="item_3" />
        <label class="checkbox">Item #3</label><br />

    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$().ready(function() {

    $('#addForm').validate({
        rules: { 
            "items": { 
                required: true, 
                minlength: 1 
            } 
        }, 
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.is(':checkbox')) {
                $(this).prev("div").addClass('checkbox-error');
            }
            else {
                 return true;
            }
         }
    }); 


});
```

CSS:

```
.error {
    background-color: #FF898D;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.checkbox-error {
    color: #FF898D;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(element).parent('div').addClass('checkbox-error');
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working.  When I check in Firebug, it adds class="error" to the first checkbox only.

Comment: Got it, 'this' should be 'element' 
`$(element).parent('div').addClass('checkbox-error');`

Comment: Ahhh, but now when a checkbox is selected, the class is not removed, and it remains in red.  How do I remove a class from the div once a checkbox is selected?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/17211258/923785 should be the accepted answer - the above leaves the error class behind after the field has been changed to valid.

Comment: Custom message are removed if i use above script

Answer (score 52):

This should work:

```
    $('#myform').validate({
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).parent().addClass("field-error");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).parent().removeClass("field-error");
    }
    });
```

Checkout the documentation for more options:

- http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer - this ensures the custom class is applied and removed whenever the validation state changes. The accepted answer will leave the error class behind even once the field has changed to be validated successfully (highlighted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941662/jquery-validate-add-error-class-to-parent-div#comment9704285_7941677)

Answer (score 6):

From my answer on [add class to parent div if validation error occurs using jquery validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39737510/1366033) because I believe it adds value to the existing answers on this question ...

## Access Validator Settings

The first order of business is to modify the `settings` object on your form's validator. You can do this in any of the following ways:

1. Before the form is loaded for all forms by calling [`jQuery.validator.setDefaults()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/)
2. When initializing the form by passing in options on [`.validate([options])`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)
3. After initialization by locating the validator object on the form with [`$("form").data("validator").settings`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4764443/1366033)

Since you're using MVC, option #2 is out of the question since [unobtrusive-validation](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) will automatically initialize the form.  So let's use option 3 going forward - the goal here is just to be able to customize the settings on the form.

## Override Default Behavior

The default methods we'll want to modify are [`highlight`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight) and [`unhighlight`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#unhighlight) which will *highlight* invalid fields or revert changes made by the highlight option, respectively.  Here's their default behavior [according to the source code](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/blob/1.16.0/src/core.js#L312):

```js
highlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    if ( element.type === "radio" ) {
        this.findByName( element.name ).addClass( errorClass ).removeClass( validClass );
    } else {
        $( element ).addClass( errorClass ).removeClass( validClass );
    }
},
unhighlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    if ( element.type === "radio" ) {
        this.findByName( element.name ).removeClass( errorClass ).addClass( validClass );
    } else {
        $( element ).removeClass( errorClass ).addClass( validClass );
    }
}
```

So you have a couple options here as well.

1. Completely replace those functions and write them on your own
2. Wrap those functions and call them like normal but add your own custom code before or after.

#### Option 1 - Replace Wholesale

This route is pretty easy. Just write whatever you want in there.  Maybe seed from the source code, maybe do your own thing.

```js
var valSettings = $("form").data("validator").settings
valSettings.highlight = function(element, errorClass, validClass) { ... }
valSettings.unhighlight = function(element, errorClass, validClass) { ... }
```

#### Option 2 - Wrap Functions

This is less intrusive so probably preferable in most cases.

Since ultimately you will be replacing the value of `valSettings.highlight`, you'll need access to a clean pristine version of the original function.  You can save your own or grab one off the global defaults

```
// original highlight function
var highlightOriginal = $("form").data("validator").settings.highlight;
var highlightDefaults = $.validator.defaults.highlight
```

In terms of wrapping JavaScript functions, there are a couple examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259530/1366033), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326693/1366033), and [here](https://blog.sentry.io/2016/02/03/wrap-javascript-functions.html)).  Here's a parsed down example from one of those, that will help bind `this` context across function calls, preserve the arity of the arguments being passed, and persist the return value:

```js
function wrap(functionToWrap, beforeFunction) {
    return function () {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        beforeFunction.apply(this, args);
        return functionToWrap.apply(this, args);
    };
};
```

Then you'll also have to quickly define whatever additional behavior you want to fire whenever the call is made.  In this case, let's find the closest parent `div` to the element and update it's classes like this:

```
function highlightDecorator(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).closest("div").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
}
```

**Wrapping It All Up** <sup>(see what I did there)</sup>

```js
$(function () {
  var valSettings = $("form").data("validator").settings
  valSettings.highlight = wrap($.validator.defaults.highlight, highlightDecorator)
  valSettings.unhighlight = wrap($.validator.defaults.unhighlight, unhighlightDecorator)
});

function wrap(functionToWrap, beforeFunction) {
  return function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    beforeFunction.apply(this, args);
    return functionToWrap.apply(this, args);
  };
};

function highlightDecorator(element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).closest("div").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
}
function unhighlightDecorator(element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).closest("div").addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
}
```

So when we combine all of the above functions, it should look something like this:

### Working Demo in Stack Snippets and [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/p2qpn8kg/)

```js
$(function () {
  var valSettings = $("form").data("validator").settings
 valSettings.highlight = wrap($.validator.defaults.highlight, highlightDecorator)
  valSettings.unhighlight = wrap($.validator.defaults.unhighlight, unhighlightDecorator)
});

function wrap(functionToWrap, beforeFunction) {
  return function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    beforeFunction.apply(this, args);
    return functionToWrap.apply(this, args);
  };
};

function highlightDecorator(element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).closest("div").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
}
function unhighlightDecorator(element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).closest("div").addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
}
```

```css
input.input-validation-error  {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.input-validation-error label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    
<form action="/Person" method="post">
  
  <div class="required">
    <label for="Name">Name <em>*</em></label>           
    <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" 
           data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required."/>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" 
          data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </div>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  
</form>
```